# Delphi ассемблер Как использую asm сохранять регистры переданных параметров в процедуру и получать Result

Tags: delphi, ассемблер

Как использую asm  сохранять регистры переданных параметров в процедуру и получать Result
задача запустить  Run с параметрами  в ней запустить Hook который вызовет RunExp
и обратно вернуть результат
нельзя использовать глобальные переменные класса

напишу псевдо как пример

```
 type
   TTestClass = class
     private
         function RunExp(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5:integer):integer;
         procedure Hook;
     public
       function Run(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5:integer):integer;
   end;

implementation

function TTestClass.Run(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5:integer):integer;
begin
    Hook;
end;
procedure TTestClass.Hook;
begin
    Result:=RunExp(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5:integer);
end;
```

теперь с asm

```
 type
   TTestClass = class
     private
         function RunExp(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5:integer):integer;
         procedure Hook;
     public
        //запуск главной
       function Run(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5:integer):integer;
   end;

implementation

function TTestClass.Run(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5:integer):integer;
begin

    //допустим  переменные равны
   s1:=12;
   s2 := 44;
   s3 := 23;
   s4 := 88;
   s5 := 100000;
   asm
     // нужно сохранить регистр параметров что бы потом передать его в  Hook

   end;
   {тут выполняется какой то другой код }

   asm
     // вставить сохраненый регистр и вызвать  Hook
     call Hook

   end;
   Result:= ...; //то что вернул  RunExp
end;
procedure TTestClass.Hook;
begin
   asm
     // нужно сохранить регистр что бы потом передать его в  RunExp

   end;

   {тут выполняется какой то другой код }


   asm
     // вставить сохраненый регистр и вызвать  RunExp
     call RunExp
    // сохранить Result от  RunExp в регистр
   end;

end;
function RunExp(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5:integer):integer;
begin
{  RunExp должен получить такие же переменные какие были переданны в   TTestClass.Run
 s1:=12;
 s2 := 44;
 s3 := 23;
 s4 := 88;
 s5 := 100000;

}
 Result:=  s1+s2+s3+s4+s5;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

Не все параметры процедур находятся в регистрах. Посмотрите описание соглашений о вызове для x86 (в Delphi используется по умолчанию register) и для 64 (тут практически одно соглашение)

> register: параметры передаются слева направо в регистрах eax, edx,
> ecx, а если параметров больше трёх — в стеке, также слева направо.
> Исходное значение указателя на вершину стека (значение регистра esp)
> возвращает вызываемая подпрограмма.

> X64: первые четыре параметра идут в целочисленные регистры, либо в
> xmm, в зависимости от типа, остальные в стек. RCX/XMM0, RDX/XMM1,
> R8/XMM2, R9/XMM3 Чистит стек вызывающая сторона

При это для методов (а у вас методы класса) первый параметр занят под `self`

По вопросу - он слишком абстрактный. Внутри одной асм вставки можно сохранить регистр в стек `push ecx` и потом восстановить его `pop ecx`, при этом следить за состоянием стека. Часть параметров, как уже выше сказано, и так находятся в стеке

Если у вас между ассемблерными вставками код на Дельфи, то за стеком не уследите. Собственно, локальные переменные внутри процедуры здесь для хранения отлично подойдут - у вас же нельзя только глобальные переменные класса использовать.

Comment: а как сохранить все аргументы в переменную и узнать общий размер всех аргументов. а когда это есть как набор этих байт в array скопировать я имеею ввиду в asm. Уменя получается частично выполнить эту задачу но либо ошибки после выполнения или не все переменные в конечную процедуру передаются верно

Comment: просто не понятно как это сделать для всех возможных вариантов аргументов. например как в rtti.invoke только там вызывает но не сохраняет входные аргументы

Comment: @Кирилл Решетников Не уверен, что универсальное решение есть и оно простое. Для целых параметров понятно, но вещественные, int64, записи и т.д. передаются через стек, под каждый отводится sizeof байтов. Может быть, можно побаловаться разницей esp и ebp на входе в процедуру. Собственно, например, `ret $0010` в конце процедуры показывает, что стековые параметры занимали 16 байт. Как это внутри процедуры получить только...